# Android crashing in the field - how to log/read events and state at time of crash?

Tags: android

I write an an Android application for an industrial process.    When I'm developing, attached to a PC, Eclipse, etc, I seldom see crashes.     But every so often I get reports from the field, or even our own in-house testers of crashes and force-stops of the app.    I can never reproduce these but I need to find out what's causing them.

I'd like to be able to get a Windows-DrWatson-style dump when a crash occurs.   What are my options for instrumenting my code to get a postmotem after a crash?    I want to read logcat messages programmatically, not attached to a PC. I'd also like a stack dump. I'd also like to know what was happening from the OS POV, e.g., what thread was running, what resources were being used, most recent TCP activity, etc, etc.

What are my best options here?   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are my options for instrumenting my code to get a postmotem after a crash?

If you are distributing this through the Play Store (doesn't seem likely in this case), if the user chooses to report the crash, it will appear in your developer console.

Otherwise, use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to have crash information sent wherever you like, or roll your own thing using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`.

Comment: It's important that I can access the crash logs programatically, so I can display the information within the program next time it's started, or in a separate program that would be run by field personnel or in-house testers.

Comment: ...(sorry, hit "Enter" too soon)  ..   Our products do not have internet access when in use.  Many are used in high-security settings where it's disallowed and blocked.    They are sold as part of a suite of products used in manufacturing and their software is preloaded during our manufacturing process.  .

Comment: @user316117: Then, as I wrote, use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` and roll your own thing.

Comment: Sure but after I land in the exception handler I still have to acquire the necessary log files, stack trace, etc.  Where can I see how to do that?

Comment: @user316117: Well, most of what you asked for is not possible ("I'd also like to know what was happening from the OS POV, e.g., what thread was running, what resources were being used, most recent TCP activity") except by making your own mobile OS. There are many examples of reading Android logs out on the Internet, such as this one: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically Getting at the stack trace is via the `Throwable` object passed to your uncaught exception handler.

Comment: Here's an idea.   Can I use ACRA anyway to just gather and format the information and then programmatically access and display what it WOULD have sent out on the web, locally, on the device?   Does it have an API for that?

Comment: @user316117: You can certainly control ACRA's delivery. By default, it writes to a Google Spreadsheet, but there should be nothing stopping you from writing the data someplace else. Personally, I haven't tried that, but AFAIK it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

i hope you can use [Application Crash Report for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) for reporting the crashes to one of your google docs.

This is very easy integrate with your existing project. They provide a very detailed help on how to start using ACRA.
You can use it for

- silent crash report
- you can notify user about the crash and then log it

In case you have any issues in using this tool, let me know. i have used this in several projects

Comment: As I explained to the prior poster, our products do not have internet/web access when they are in use.   So crash information must be saved and displayed locally on the device.